# High Sierra Screenshot part of screen stopped working

Tags: screen-capture

I have been for years using `shift+cmd+4` to take a screenshot of only a part of the screen, or just to measure some distance in an image. A week or so ago it completely changed functionality to instead take a screenshot of the entire hovered window... Why?? I need it back.. I get designs as JPG's :D and need to implement websites base on that :P

I haven't installed anything that I can think of, I got a new external screen but that was plug & play, a DELL screen. It can't be that can it??

Attaching a photo of how it looks below, note the blue tint that the window is selected and the camera icon in the middle..

[image]

Comment: I also got a cordless Apple Mouse "Magic Mouse" and an Apple keyboard

Comment: I unplugged the screen, mouse & keyboard but it was still the same

Comment: Tapping the spacebar should toggle between 'drag a box' & 'whole window' behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin you're my angel! Thank you so much!! Post it as an answer and score some points! :)

Comment: The default for my screen capture changed suddenly also - strange!!

Comment: @Seamus not strange but super annoying, I feel like throwing my mac off a cliff sometimes due to things like this.. and it crashing occationally.. RIP Steve Jobs.. Macs were better in his time.. 

Btw it means you should upvote my question also :D

Comment: Indeed it does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what has prompted it to default to 'whole window' - usually 'selected area' is the default, however, tapping the Space Bar should toggle the behaviour back & forth for that session.